# Upgrade Outdated Python Packages by PIP in PowerShell in One Line

Tags: powershell, pip, pipe

How to upgrade outdated Python packages by PIP in **PowerShell** in one line?

A few days ago,  I created an issue in [pypa / pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues), to ask why [package names could not be passed as object in PowerShell](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8503) by

```
pip list --outdated | Select-Object Package
```

The developer advised to use

```
py -m pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-JSON
```

Now it seems that

```
((pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-JSON).name | Out-String).replace("`r`n"," ")
```

outputs outdated packages split in space:

````
idna ipykernel ipython jedi jupyter-client jupyterlab jupyterlab-server lxml Pillow setuptools```
````

```
pip install ((pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-JSON).name | Out-String).replace("`r`n"," ")
```

does not work:

> ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'idna ipykernel ipython jedi jupyter-client jupyterlab jupyterlab-server lxml Pillow setuptools'

However, if I use **`Write-Output`**:

```
Write-Output "pip install -U" ((pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-JSON).name | Out-String).replace("`r`n"," ")
```

it outputs

```
pip install -U
idna ipykernel ipython jedi jupyter-client jupyterlab jupyterlab-server lxml Pillow setuptools
```

which is split into two lines and cannot be executed by **`Invoke-Expression`**.

If I use **`Write-Host`**:

```
Write-Host "pip install -U" ((pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-JSON).name | Out-String).replace("`r`n"," ") | Invoke-Expression
```

It just outputs normally but doesn't execute:

````
pip install -U idna ipykernel ipython jedi jupyter-client jupyterlab jupyterlab-server lxmlPillow setuptools```
````

It's acceptable to do this in two lines:

```
$od = ((pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-JSON).name | Out-String).replace("`r`n"," ")
Write-Output "pip install -U $od" | Invoke-Expression
```

But, just for my curiosity, can this be written in one line?

Answer (score 0):

I keep forgetting how to do this, so I'm pasting the command here as a memo:

```
pip install -U (pip list --outdated --format=json | ConvertFrom-JSON | ForEach {$_.name})
```

Tested on PowerShell 7.4.1.